# Lookup value is not populating in url hack custom button in lightning

Tags: lightning, custom-button, urlhacking

```
/lightning/o/Request__c/new?&recordTypeId=0100C000000Sjk1&
defaultFieldValues=Request_Name__c={!Request__c.Request_Name__c},
Account_owner__c={!Request__c.AccountId}
```

Above piece of code is written on custom button for url in lightning hack and when i click on that button in lighning request name is showing in custom_clone Button but account name is not showing in lookup field.

Comment: Is `Account_owner__c` the lookup to account?

Comment: yes it is lookup to account @rahulgawale

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see you have a custom object `Request__c`. The `AccountId` is not the correct API name for the Account field.

It has to have `__c` at the end. I presume that your field API name is `AccountId__c`

```
/lightning/o/Request__c/new?&recordTypeId=0100C000000Sjk1&
defaultFieldValues=Request_Name__c={!Request__c.Request_Name__c},
Account_owner__c={!Request__c.AccountId__c}
```

Just put the correct API name here and make sure the User have an access to that field.